# App launching and then closing from Testflight

Tags: ios9, xcode7

I've got an app that runs perfectly well when run from the debugger. When uploading to TestFlight it goes through fine and am able to download using the Testflight app.

However, the moment I launch the app, it displays the splash for 20 or so seconds before closing. No crash report as such is generated but was able to extra a '.ips.beta' file from CrashReporter and it looks like this:

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
Highlighted by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.some.app failed to launch after 20.00s (launchIntent: foreground-interactive)

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 30.760 (user 30.760, system 0.000), 77% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.080, 0% CPU

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3805e3c0 0x38048000 + 91072
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f749a6 0x37f64000 + 68006
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f66b2e 0x37f64000 + 11054

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3805d54c 0x38048000 + 87372
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f727f0 0x37f64000 + 59376
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f727da 0x37f64000 + 59354
```

I can see it says '8 bad food' and that it's closing before it's able to initialize - but - it produces no statements in the console, and it's running absolutely perfectly on a device when run using the Debugger or even when I install a Adhoc copy (manually from Xcode or using Fabric). Why would it fail only when coming from TestFlight? How do I go about debugging this when it's working fine otherwise. It's failing on every device that it otherwise is able to run using the debugger.

I have even tried putting a NSLog statement in the main() method before the delegate gets passed control - that doesn't get logged to the console (I'm using the Device Manager to see raw device logs). Furthermore, every time I launch the app, I see this before the app closes:

AppName[640] : Bogus event received by listener connection:
     { count = 1, contents =
        "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a TestFlight app thinning bug, it's corrupting the binaries:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17583